# What is なっとらんかった?

Tags: grammar, words, colloquial-language, kansai-ben

> 拍子抜けって言えば拍子抜けやなぁ。どこも大事には**なっとらんかった**みたいやし....なんか踊らせてた感があるわ

I don't understand what this part means. I tried looking it up but I can't find anything. Is it a single word?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なっとらん <sup>Kansai-ben</sup> = なってない <sup>Hyōjungo</sup>

> どこも大事にはなってなかったみたいですし

Comment: However I am too weak for an exact translation without a broader context ...never got into anything serious? ...never treated seriously?

Comment: never got into anything serious がいいと思います。この場合は「[大事]{だいじ}に[至]{いた}らなかった」と同じ意味だと思います。